# Facebook Style Messaging System in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How would I do make a Facebook style messaging system (based on this http://www.9lessons.info/2013/05/message-conversation-database-design.html) in SQLAlchemy and Flask?
Here are my models currently but I keep on getting an Ambiguous Foreign Keys Error, I assume based on my Conversation Table.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(12), unique=False)
    conversation = db.relationship('Conversation',backref='user',lazy='dynamic')
    conversation_reply = db.relationship('Conversation_Reply',backref='user',lazy='dynamic')

class Conversation(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user1 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    user2 = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    conversation_reply = db.relationship('Conversation_Reply',backref='conversation',lazy='dynamic')

class Conversation_Reply(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    reply = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id_fk = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    c_id_fk = db.Column(db.String(11), db.ForeignKey("conversation.id"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to specify the join condition to get both conversations if the user was user1 or was user2, you could do something like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    # ...
    # Converstations where either user1 or user2 is this user.
    all_conversations = db.relationship('Conversation',
        primaryjoin='or_(User.id == Conversation.user1_id, User.id == ' \
        'Conversation.user2_id)', lazy='dynamic')
    # Replies where this is this user.
    replies = db.relationship("Reply", backref="user")

class Conversation(db.Model):
    # ...
    user1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    user2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))        
    user1 = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[user1_id], 
        backref='conversations_as_user1')       
    user2 = db.relationship('User', foreign_keys=[user2_id], 
        backref='conversations_as_user2')
    # Replies to this conversation.
    replies = db.relationship("Reply", backref="conversation")

class Reply(db.Model):
    # ...
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    conversation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("conversation.id"))
```

You might want to change user1 and user2 to `from_user` and `to_user` based on who started the conversation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Only thing I've noticed is that SQLAlchemy raises an interface error for the reply table when you try to commit anything to the database. Any idea why that could be happening? `class Reply(db.Model):
    #id
    reply = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    conversation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("conversation.id"))

    def __init__(self,reply, user_id, conversation_id):
        self.reply = reply
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.conversation_id = conversation_id`

Comment: What is the actual error?  Do you have a primary key, the code you posted in the last comment looks like the id is commented out?

Comment: The actual error is "sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError" when I try to commit the Reply object to the database. I commented out the id just to save space since StackOverflow has limited characters on comments. Any idea why this is happening?